# circle radius from two points and the angle of one tangent with the horizontal axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I want to find the radius $R$ knowing

- the coordinates of two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$
- the angle $\alpha$ between a tangent to the circle passing by $(x_1,y_1)$ and the horizontal

[image: find R]

Note that $x_1$<$x_2$ and $0\le\alpha<\pi$

---

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996582/finding-circle-with-two-points-on-it-and-a-tangent-from-one-of-the-points) but I think it's possible to find a geometric answer that does not involve solving a system of equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centre of the circle has coordinates $$(x_1+R\sin\alpha, y_1-R\cos\alpha)$$

If $P=(x_2, y_2)$, then considering the distance
 $CP^2$, 
$$(x_1-x_2)^2+2R(x_1-x_2)\sin\alpha+R^2\sin^2\alpha+(y_1-y_2)^2-2R(y_1-y_2)\cos\alpha+R^2\cos^2\alpha=R^2$$

Now you can cancel terms and rearrange to get $R$

Comment: Just want to add an extra info. The equation thus set up will NOT be a quadratic.

Comment: @Mick| yes, the $R^2$ terms cancel